# How to install MariaDB on RHEL 7 server?

Tags: mariadb, yum, rhel7

Given `cat /etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo` is:

```
# MariaDB 10.3 RedHat repository list - created 2018-08-29 05:52 UTC
# http://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.3/rhel7-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
```

When I do

```
sudo yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client
```

I got:

```
Loaded plugins: search-disabled-repos
No package MariaDB-server available.
  * Maybe you meant: mariadb-server
No package MariaDB-client available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I'm using https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=digital-pacific&distro=RedHat&distro_release=rhel7-amd64--rhel7&version=10.3

Why am I not able to install mariadb on my RHEL7 server?

Note:

```
yum list mariadb
Loaded plugins: search-disabled-repos
Available Packages
mariadb.x86_64                                      1:5.5.60-1.el7_5                                      uofa_repos
```

Is this because i'm only looking at uofa_repos repository somehow? How do I install mariadb correctly?

Answer (score 2):

After adding the Repo, as you did, run: (This should force reload the repository)

```
sudo yum clean all
```

Then run: (This will list the available repository for MariaDB).

```
sudo yum list --showduplicates MariaDB-server
```

This will show something like:

```
    Available Packages
    mariadb-server.x86_64
    .........
```

Now pay Attention to the name of the package (sudo yum install is **case sensitive**) so in this example run:

```
sudo yum install mariadb-server
```

(Not MariaDB-server)

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [baseurl](http://yum.mariadb.org/10.3/rhel7-amd64/rpms/) as given you will notice things are not named as you might expect them to be;

`MariaDB-10.3.7-centos73-x86_64-client.rpm
MariaDB-10.3.9-centos73-x86_64-server.rpm`

It looks like you should specify something along the lines of `yum install MariaDB-10.3.9-centos73-x86_64-<foo>` in order to install from that specific repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you got this error: No package MariaDB-server and No package MariaDB-client. Just comment this line in **/etc/yum.conf** (add # at the beginning...)

```
#exclude=ansible1.9,mysql,mariadb,mariadb-,Percona-XtraDB-,Percona--55,Percona--56,Percona--51,Percona--50
```